# Mule ESB returns my XML as <string>xml</string> instead of proper XML

Tags: xml, web, service, mule

my Mule flow when tested with my web browser as a client is returning my expected `XML` result as a long XML-like string surrounded by "`string`" tags instead of properly formatted `XML` without the "`string`" tags.  i.e. I get

```
  <string><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><scan><patient_fname>John</patient_fname><scan_id>41fc14e761024d65eb3f31e6f6ff9abb</scan_id><patient_lname>Smith</patient_lname><crtransform>0.3802383 -0.2290233 -0.8960843 68.6041674 0.8808550 0.3850588 0.2753618 -10.1133584 0.2819809 -0.8940235 0.3481504 23.7410466 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000</crtransform><datetime>1393790925155012</datetime><cotransform></cotransform><ormco_id>1111121</ormco_id><patient_gender>M</patient_gender><uploads_complete>True</uploads_complete><doctor_email_id>abcde</doctor_email_id><patient_dob>1986-06-27</patient_dob></scan></string>
```

from Mule instead of what I need (and get when by-passing Mule and requesting directly on the `RESTful` web service:

```
<scan>
  <patient_fname>John</patient_fname
  <scan_id>41fc14e761024d65eb3f31e6f6ff9abb</scan_id
  <patient_lname>Smith</patient_lname>
  <crtransform>0.3802383 -0.2290233 -0.8960843 68.6041674 0.8808550 0.3850588 0.2753618 -10.1133584 0.2819809 -0.8940235 0.3481504 23.7410466 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 1.0000000</crtransform>
  <datetime>1393790925155012</datetime>
  <cotransform/>
  <ormco_id>1111121</ormco_id>
  <patient_gender>M</patient_gender>
  <uploads_complete>True</uploads_complete>
  <doctor_email_id>abcde</doctor_email_id>
  <patient_dob>1986-06-27</patient_dob>
</scan>
```

Here's the relevant section of the Mule flow:

```
...
<choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[message.inboundProperties['format'] == 'xml']">
            <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="Object to XML"/>
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" doc:name="text/xml content-type"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere `XML` is converted to `String` with `<object-to-string-transformer>` or in `component` or other place.